# Docker commands require keyboard interaction

Tags: docker, interactive, apt

I'm trying to create a Docker image for ripping CDs (using abcde).
Here's the relevant portion of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:17.10
MAINTAINER Graham Nicholls <graham@rockcons.co.uk>
RUN apt update && apt -y install eject vim ruby abcde
...
```

Unfortunately, the package "abcde" pulls in a mail client (not sure which), and apt tries to configure that by asking what type of mail connection to configure (smarthost/relay etc).

When docker runs, it's not appearing to read from stdin, so I can't redirect into the docker process.

I've tried using `--nodeps` with apt (and replacing apt with apt-get); unfortunately `--nodeps` seems no-longer to be a supported option and returns:

> E: Command line option --nodeps is not understood in combination with the other options

Someone has suggested using expect in response to a similar question, which I'd rather avoid. This seems to be a "difficult to google" problem - I can't find anything.

So, is there a way of passing in the answer to the config in apt, or of preventing apt from pulling in a mail client, which would be better - I'm not planning in sending updates to cddb.

Comment: Usually, in the context of a docker build, `apt` installs are non-interactive (because there is no tty).  Does setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` (e.g., via an `ENV` statement in your Dockerfile before the package installs) stop the package from prompting?

Comment: @larsks- thanks, but no difference, sadly. Oh hang on - just properly read your comment; let me try putting it in the Dockerfile...  Which works, so thanks!  BUT: what about the answer generically - that's extremely useful for an apt command, but what about in general where I need to redirect an answer in from a file?

Comment: @Dan Lowe: Thanks for the edit, but I'm not arguing with anyone - answers suggesting a different ripper don't address the generic question, which was the point I was making.

Comment: @GrahamNicholls I didn't make that edit, the editor before me made that edit. You can click on the "edited ... ago" link to view the full edit history.

Comment: @DanLowe OIC, sorry!

Comment: @larsks    Thanks that _does_ work.   still looking for a generic solution, though.

Comment: Regarding "generic answer" you can always do: `yes | command`, i.e. `RUN yes | apt .....`. It is like having an user hitting yes yes yes yes...

Comment: @Robert That will only work if the command reads from stdin.  This doesn't which is what expect is for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The typical template to install apt packages in a docker container looks like:

```
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    eject \
    vim \
    ruby \
    abcde \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Running it with the "noninteractive" value removes any prompts. You don't want to set that as an `ENV` since that would also impact any interactive commands you run inside the container.

You also want to cleanup the package database when finished to reduce the layer size and avoid reusing a stale cached package database in a later step.

The no-install-recommends option will reduce the number of packages installed by only installing the required dependencies, not the additional recommended packages. This cuts the size of the root filesystem down by half for me.

---

If you need to pass a non-default configuration to a package, then use debconf. First run you install somewhere interactively and enter the options you want to save. Install `debconf-utils`. Then run:

```
debconf-get-selections | grep "${package_name}"
```

to view all the options you configured for that package. You can then pipe these options to `debconf-set-selections` in your container before running your install, e.g.:

```
RUN echo "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type        select  No configuration" \
  | debconf-set-selections \
 && apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
 ....
```

or save your selections to a file that you copy in:

```
COPY debconf-selections /
RUN debconf-set-selections </debconf-selections \
 && apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
 ....
```

Comment: thanks - as an aside I read that apt now replaces apt-get (I'm sure there's a good reason).  Presumably this advice all still applies?  Also, presumably setting the ENV variable would only effect those commands which honour "DEBIAN_FRONTEND" ?    But still, I do prefer using the format of setting a variable for the command only - it seems cleaner.  PS Good catch on the apt clean.

Comment: My old `apt-get` habits die hard, I haven't checked if `apt` changed any of this, but I doubt it. The `ENV` would affect any commands using that variable, including interactive commands that you run inside the container after building your image. It can be very non-intuitive to users of the image to have this variable defined after build.

Comment: I was just in the shower, and had the epiphany that by using ENV, the var would be set in the container.  This would as you say, have an unexpected consequence.